# C# Linq .Find() return many results

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a simple search function for my application. I am using Linq's .Find() method to search through a list of objects. It all works very well, the only problem I'm currently having is that I only get the first result. I know for a fact that there are more than one results to be had, but I only get one. Here is my code:

```
case 5: {
    //Search for Price

    Product searchResult = tempList.Find(x => x.getPrice() == searchPrice);
    if (searchResult != null) {
        //Present Result
        searchTable.Rows.Add(convertIDValue(searchResult.getProductID()), searchResult.getTitle(), searchResult.getYear(), searchResult.getAmount(), searchResult.getPrice());
    }
    else {
        MessageBox.Show("No product with that price", "0 results");
    }

    break;
}
```

I thought I could change `Product searchResult` into `List<Product> searchResults` in order to get a list of Products, then loop through that list. But that gave me an error saying:

> Cannot implicitly convert type '.Product' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<.Product>

Is there any way to get Linq's .Find() to return multiple results?

Comment: Use `.Where` instead of Find and put `.ToList()` at the end. Problem solved

Comment: Note that `Find` isn't part of LINQ. It also looks like you really need to embrace .NET conventions - properties instead of methods, naming etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Where()` and `ToList()` to get all objects, matching the condition into a `List`

replace

```
Product searchResult = tempList.Find(x => x.getPrice() == searchPrice);
```

with

```
List<Product> searchResult = tempList.Where(x => x.getPrice() == searchPrice).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a [`FindAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z(v=vs.110).aspx) method for that purpose:

```
List<Product> products = tempList.FindAll(x => x.getPrice() == searchPrice);
```

Answer (score 2):

> `Find()` searches for an element that matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate, and returns the first occurrence within the entire List.

You need to use `FindAll()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft explains the "Find()" method :"Searches for an element that matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate, and returns the first occurrence within the entire List."

I would suggest you to use this [Where() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) from Linq extension.

Don't forget to **import** "using System.Linq" in your current class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Product searchResult =
```

means you are declaring one element. The thing you need is a collection of products, like:

```
IEnumerable<product> searchResult  =
```

The easiest way to do it is to  change Find() to where():

```
IEnumerable<product> searchResult = tempList.Where(x => x.getPrice() == searchPrice);
```

this will create some collection of product's. It will be easier to maintain as a list, so:

```
list<product> searchResult = tempList.Where(x => x.getPrice() == searchPrice).toList();
```

Read about IEnumerable interface :)